# Grouping by category

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called data having a column called empid
Select category from production

```
Empid
------
50011
50012
51011
52013
50014
55015
55016
```

In this data first 2 digit mentioned a department.. example 50 is one department 51 is another department i want to split id department wise in the below format,in Oracle SQL query

```
Dept0   Dept1.  Dept3.   dept4.  Dept5
50011.  51011   52013.   0.      55015
50012.   0.     0.       0.      55016 
50014.   0.     0.       0.          0
```

Comment: How many departments do you have?

Comment: More than 10 departments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses conditional aggregation using `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when empid like '50%' then empid else 0 end) as dept0,
       max(case when empid like '51%' then empid else 0 end) as dept1,
       max(case when empid like '53%' then empid else 0 end) as dept3,
       max(case when empid like '54%' then empid else 0 end) as dept4,
       max(case when empid like '55%' then empid else 0 end) as dept5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by substr(empid, 1, 2) order by empid) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by seqnum;
```